# Square roots of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

My book says that given the complex number $z$ with modulus $r$, its square roots are $±√re^{iΘ/2}$ where $Θ$ is the *principal* value of $\arg z$. My question is that why must we consider the principal value of its argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider the principal value by convention. But also if we take the other value $\frac{\theta}{2}+\pi$ we find the same two roots because $e^{i(\frac{\theta}{2}+\pi)}=-e^{i(\frac{\theta}{2})}$

Answer (score 1):

You must not consider the principal value of the argument ! If $z=re^{i \phi}$ with $r \ge 0$ and $ \phi \in \mathbb R$, then put

$w_1:= \sqrt{r} e^{i \frac{\phi}{2}}$ and $w_2:=-w_1$.

Then we have

$$w_1^2=z=w_2^2.$$

Comment: I'm sorry. I messed up while writing the question. I edited it now. But my point is, the $φ$ in your answer need not be the principal argument.

Comment: No. The $ \phi$ in my answer can be any(!) argument of $z$. It is easy to see that $w_1^2=z=w_2^2.$. If $z \ne 0$, then the equation $w^2=z$ has exactly two solutions. $w_1$ and $w_2$ are solutions of this equation. Conclusion .... ?